# Check If User Subscription Is In Date - Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this code in my login script to check if the users subscription is in date:

```
// get the current date
$now = date("Y-m-d");
    if ($user_id['enddate'] < $now) {
      ?>
      <p>your Licence is out of date</p>
      <?php
      }
else
      {
      ?>
      <p>your licence is in date</p>
      <?php
      }
```

The value storing the expiry date is 'enddate'.

It just goes straight to the out of date message, whether the user has a subscription in date or not. I can't get my head around it.

The MYSQL field for enddate is just type 'date', and is generated from the registration script:

```
$enddate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 365 day"));
```

Any ideas? I know i'm working in depreciated MYSQL, but I need to for this project.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert to time, date is just a string...

```
$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
if (strtotime($user_id['enddate']) < $now) {
  ?>
  <p>your Licence is out of date</p>
  <?php
  }
else
  {
  ?>
  <p>your licence is in date</p>
  <?php
  }
```

Comment: `echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));`

`echo strtotime($user_id['enddate']);`


What do you get?

Comment: Looks like you need to get $user_id['enddate'] set to the end date, if its nothing then that is the issue.

Comment: SOLVED! I got it to work with this:
`$end = mysql_query("SELECT enddate FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION["user_id"]."'"); echo $query;
$end1 = mysql_result($end, 0);
$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
if (strtotime($end1) < $now) {`
Cheers Dave!

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Solved with the following:

```
$expirydate = mysql_query("SELECT enddate FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION["user_id"]."'"); echo $query;
$expirydate2 = mysql_result($end, 0);
$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
if (strtotime($expirydate2) < $now) {
```

Hope this is of help to some of you.